# How to get the real display size in Android

Tags: java, android

I try to get the disply size in Android (in a Java-Class). 
I used the methods:

```
display.getSize(size);
display.getRealSize(size);
```

but both return a correct result for width but the height value is to high.
Has anyone a suggestion, why I get the wrong result ?

Gruß, Andre

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int w = dm.widthPixels
int h = dm.heightPixels
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can get information about your screen from [DisplayMetrics class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html)

```
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    int width = dm.widthPixels;
    int height = dm.heightPixels;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty well documented here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html

> getSize()
>
> Gets the size of the display, in pixels.
>
> **The size returned by this method does not necessarily represent the actual raw size (native resolution) of the display. The returned size
>   may be adjusted to exclude certain system decoration elements that are
>   always visible.** It may also be scaled to provide compatibility with
>   older applications that were originally designed for smaller displays.

and

> getRealSize()
>
> Gets the real size of the display **without subtracting any window decor
>   or applying any compatibility scale factors.**
>
> The size is adjusted based on the current rotation of the display.
>
> The real size may be smaller than the physical size of the screen when
>   the window manager is emulating a smaller display (using adb shell am
>   display-size).

I made the important parts bold